# Assign Static IP address (Elastic IP) / Private link for VNet-injected Databricks workspaces in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

We wanted to create a private link/static IP in order to access data lake storage from Databricks in Azure that would create a secure connection to data lake storage for data movement activities.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using [Private endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-storage-portal) in ADLS. Detailed steps are given in [databricks documentation](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/02/28/securely-accessing-azure-data-sources-from-azure-databricks.html)